# How do I use unread() in PushBackBufferedInputStream after the stream is empty?

Tags: java, bufferedstream

Making a Lexical Analyzer in Java and I'm using PushbackInputStream because I need to be able to push back what I read in case it's not what I wanted. But whenever the stream is empty and read() returns -1. It doesn't allow me to use unread().

EDIT: I'm currently using a regular InputStream, reading it all at once, putting it into a stack, and using  the stack as the stream so I can pop() and push() items on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are using a crufty 3rd-party pushback stream.

You probably should be using `java.io.PushbackInputStream` or `java.io.PushbackReader` which have a more clearly specified API, and don't do peculiar things like "flushing" the buffer.

Comment: Oops! I was actually using java.io.PushbackInputStream. But at the time of posting this I was at school and didn't have access to my code so couldn't remember exactly what I used.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get by with single token look-ahead and push-back, the quaintly venerable [`StreamTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) class may suffice. It's used in this simple [implementation](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) of a recursive descent parser.

Comment: Wow thanks but I actually have to code the Tokenizer myself lol.

Answer (score 0):

> But whenever the stream is empty and
>   read() returns -1. It doesn't allow me
>   to use unread().

Please elaborate 'doesn't allow me to use unread()'. From a quick look at the source code it should work OK.

Also curious to know why you are pushing back at EOF.

Comment: It was giving me an IOException. In the case where the stream is something like "FOO" and I'm trying to find "FOL". I'll read the first two characters, they will match. But when I read the third it won't. So I need to put those 3 characters back into the empty stream so I can match it with something else.

Comment: What was the text of the IOException?

Comment: Nothing because I was using catch. >.>

Comment: So? That doesn't stop the IOException having text. It doesn't answer the question either.